# How to add plus and minus button on products list in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1.9

I want add to cart button should turn into a plus (+) or minus (-) button upon clicking (quantity should be update cart on click + and -). On the product listing also home page update (+ or -) product's quantity into the cart. This is urgent if anyone have any solution please comment.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you update any screenshot?

Comment: I have edit code please review it . this code working for me

Comment: This is working on + and - increment and decrement fcuntionality but  we want to increment cart products quantity on click + and decerment the cart quantity on click - ,